# What is the exothermic reaction of superglue with cardboard?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers, heat

I glued a sheet of paper to a cardboard package using superglue (labelled with ethyl 2-cyanoacrylate).
To my surprise the paper became very warm.
What kind of reaction is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is due to the fact that cyanoacrylates polymerize by anionic (or sufficiently strong neutral nucleophile) addition. In particular, they react with hydroxyl ($\ce{-OH}$) groups; paper, being primarily [cellulose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose), is abundant in hydroxyls. The bond formation involved in the polymerization reaction is inherently exothermic (generating a $\ce{C-O}$ bond on initiation and many subsequent $\ce{C-C}$ bonds as the polymerization proceeds), and with a large surface area and many reactive groups, I could certainly imagine the reaction being surprisingly violent. The Wikipedia page on cyanoacrylates notes its [reactivity with cotton fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate#Reaction_with_cotton) (again, being chiefly composed of cellulose), and the MSDSs for various similar compounds warn of exothermic reaction with paper and similar materials (q.v., [1](http://www.tedpella.com/msds_html/10035%20msds%20mfg.pdf), [2](http://www.adhesive.com/resources/MSDS/i5-Instant-Adhesive-MSDS.pdf), [3](https://cyberbond1com.blob.core.windows.net/multimedia/pdfs/5008%20MSDS.pdf)).